# iOS app conflict if the same app has been uploaded to website for download first using Enterprise, then later uploaded to appstore?

Tags: ios, app-store, mobile-application, enterprise

So I already uploaded my iOS app to a website for download. My friends already downloaded it into their devices. And it has been quite awhile (2 weeks).

Now I decided to publish the same app in AppStore.

Would there be any conflict for this app when downloading from website and later download it again from Appstore?
Any download/update issue?

What if I use a different `bundle id`?

What if I use the same `bundle id`?

What if I change the `app version`?

Can an app with the same `bundle ID` be uploaded to both `Enterprise Account` and `Appstore Account`?

Also other possible scenarios?

Thank you.

I am looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What if I use a different bundle id?

Then they're two different apps with the same name and icon, but for iOS they'll be installed in separate folders, different keychain entries, UserDefaults, etc.

> What if I use the same bundle id?

If you distributed a Testflight build exported from Xcode, then they install from App Store as long as the build number is bigger only the binaries will be updated: no data loss.

> What if I change the app version?

That's a new version of your app, so nothing wrong here, in fact, I'll bump the app version before sending it to Apple, so this version has a bigger version number than the Testflight ones. You should use [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) for this.

Comment: I see. I am going to ask you a similar question. Can an app with the same `bundle ID` be uploaded to both `Enterprise Account` and `Appstore Account`?

Comment: Never done it but I assume you can’t, as the app is will be same for both

Comment: So I have to use different  bundle IDs. Now I'm gonna deploy my app to app store with a different bundle id. Since I already have the same app in Enterprise, would there any problem ? Should I delete it from the Enterprise program? Or is it okay to keep it while deploying another one to App Store? Do you have any document I can read about this?